# What is wrong with Wix my Bootstrap with SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: wix

I have this bootstrap project that needs to detect if SQL Server is installed or not. If it is installed, then it skips the installing. If it is not, it should then installs SQL Express 2012. The exe installer was compiled fine, however, when I was testing the installer, I always got this error and I can't find any reason that is wrong. The machine I was testing on had the SQL server installed but it still detects no SQL installed. It then continue to install but it gets the Error 0x858c0014: Process returned error: 
Failed to execute EXE package. Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.

Here is my wxs file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
 xmlns:dep="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/DependencyExtension">
 <?define InstanceName = "SQLEXPRESS" ?>
 <Bundle Name="EasyLobby11 Database Setup" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft"      UpgradeCode="4f09f7d9-f894-42b2-a865-6ae460a09c7e">
<BootstrapperApplicationRef
 Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Sql2012Express"/>
</Chain>

</Bundle>
 <Fragment>
 <util:RegistrySearch
   Id="SqlInstanceKeyFound"
   Root="HKLM"
   Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
   Value="InstanceName"
   Result="exists"
   Variable="SqlInstanceKeyFound" />

<util:RegistrySearch
    Id="SqlInstanceKey"
    Root="HKLM"
    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
    Value="InstanceName"
    Variable="SqlInstanceKey"
    After="SqlInstanceKeyFound"
    Condition="SqlInstanceKeyFound" />

<util:RegistrySearch
   Id="SqlInstanceFound"
   Root="HKLM"
   Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SqlInstanceKey]"
   Result="exists"
   Variable="SqlInstanceFound"
   After="SqlInstanceKey"
   Condition="SqlInstanceKeyFound" />

<util:RegistrySearch
  Id="SqlVersion"
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SqlInstanceKey]\Setup"
  Value="Version"
  Variable="SqlVersion"
  After="SqlInstanceKey"
  Condition="SqlInstanceFound" />   

<PackageGroup Id="Sql2012Express">
  <ExePackage
     Id="Sql2012Express"
     DisplayName="Installing SQL Server Express 2012"
     SourceFile="SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
     Name="SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
     DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/2/9/529FEF7B-2EFB-439E-A2D1-  A1533227CD69/SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe "
     Compressed="no"
     PerMachine="yes"
     Cache ="yes"
     InstallCondition="(Not SqlInstanceKeyFound) AND (NOT SqlInstanceFound)"
     DetectCondition= "SqlInstanceFound"
     Vital="yes"
     Permanent="yes"
         InstallCommand="/ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=$(var.InstanceName)   /FEATURES=SQL /SECURITYMODE=SQL [SqlVariable] /TCPENABLED=1 /SQLSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'&quot; /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Manual /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=FALSE /Q /HIDECONSOLE /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms"
     UninstallCommand="/Action=Uninstall /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName /FEATURES=SQL /Q /HIDECONSOLE"
     RepairCommand="/ACTION=Repair /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName /Q /HIDECONSOLE">
    <ExitCode Value ="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
    <dep:Provides DisplayName="Net2 SQL Server 2012 Express"     Key="SQLServer2012Express,$(var.InstanceName)" Version="11.0.3000.0" />
  </ExePackage>     

  <ExePackage Id="Sql2012ExpressUpgrade"
    DisplayName="SQL Server 2012 Express Upgrade"
    Cache="no"
    Compressed="no"
    PerMachine="yes"
    Permanent="yes"
    Vital="yes"
    Name="SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
    SourceFile="SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
    DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/2/9/529FEF7B-2EFB-439E-A2D1-A1533227CD69/SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe "
    InstallCondition="(Not SqlInstanceKeyFound) AND (NOT SqlInstanceFound)"          
        InstallCommand="/ACTION=Upgrade /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName /Q /HIDECONSOLE /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms"

    DetectCondition="NOT (SqlInstanceFound AND (SqlVersion &lt; v11.0.0.0))">

    <ExitCode Value ="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
  </ExePackage>

  <ExePackage Id="Sql2012ExpressEditionUpgrade"
    DisplayName="SQL Server 2012 SP1 Express Patch"
    Cache="no"
    Compressed="no"
    PerMachine="yes"
    Permanent="yes"
    Vital="yes"
    Name="SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
    SourceFile="SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
    DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/2/9/529FEF7B-2EFB-439E-A2D1-A1533227CD69/SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe "
    InstallCondition="(Not SqlInstanceKeyFound) AND (NOT SqlInstanceFound)"          
    InstallCommand="/ACTION=Patch /INSTANCENAME=$(var.InstanceName) /Q /HIDECONSOLE /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms"
    DetectCondition="NOT (SqlInstanceFound AND (SqlVersion &gt; v11.0.0.0) AND (SqlVersion &lt; v11.0.3000.0))">
    <ExitCode Value ="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
  </ExePackage>
</PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuring SQL is quite a complicated job.

I just started working on Wix Packaging recently for my project.
I actually took your configuration to start with and done a few tweaks to the configuration.
I am also handling x86 and x64 packaging based on system type.

You can omit any of them if they are not relevant to you.
Hence, I am publishing a working copy of my configuration, so that it might help you.

```
<Fragment>

<?define InstanceName = "SQLEXPRESS" ?>

<util:RegistrySearch Id="SQL2012x64InstanceExists"
                    Variable="SQL2012x64InstanceExists"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
                    Value="$(var.InstanceName)"
                    Win64="yes"
                    Result="exists"/>
<util:RegistrySearch Id="SQL2012x64InstanceKey"
                     Variable="SQL2012x64InstanceKey"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
                     Value="$(var.InstanceName)"
                     Win64="yes"
                     After="SQL2012x64InstanceExists"
                     Condition="SQL2012x64InstanceExists" />
<util:RegistrySearch Id="SQL2012x64InstanceInstalled"
                     Variable="SQL2012x64InstanceInstalled"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SQL2012x64InstanceKey]"
                     Result="exists"
                     Win64="yes"
                     After="SQL2012x64InstanceKey"
                     Condition="SQL2012x64InstanceExists" />
<util:RegistrySearch Id="SQLx64Version"
                     Variable="SQLx64Version"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SQL2012x64InstanceKey]\Setup"
                     Value="Version"
                     Win64="yes"
                     After="SQL2012x64InstanceKey"
                     Condition="SQL2012x64InstanceInstalled" />

<util:RegistrySearch Id="SQL2012x86InstanceExists"
                     Variable="SQL2012x86InstanceExists"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
                     Value="$(var.InstanceName)"
                     Win64="no"
                     Result="exists"/>
<util:RegistrySearch Id="SQL2012x86InstanceKey"
                     Variable="SQL2012x86InstanceKey"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
                     Value="$(var.InstanceName)"
                     Win64="no"
                     After="SQL2012x86InstanceExists"
                     Condition="SQL2012x86InstanceExists" />
<util:RegistrySearch Id="SQL2012x86InstanceInstalled"
                     Variable="SQL2012x86InstanceInstalled"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SQL2012x86InstanceKey]"
                     Result="exists"
                     Win64="no"
                     After="SQL2012x86InstanceKey"
                     Condition="SQL2012x86InstanceExists" />
<util:RegistrySearch Id="SQLx86Version"
                     Variable="SQLx86Version"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SQL2012x86InstanceKey]\Setup"
                     Value="Version"
                     Win64="no"
                     After="SQL2012x86InstanceKey"
                     Condition="SQL2012x86InstanceInstalled" />

<PackageGroup Id="SQLServer2012Express">

  <ExePackage Id="SQL2012Expressx64"
             InstallCondition="VersionNT64 AND NOT SQL2012x64InstanceInstalled"
             SourceFile="$(var.MyDir)\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"
             DisplayName="Installing Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 - Express Edition..."
             InstallCommand="/ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /Q /HIDECONSOLE /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE&quot; /AGTSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE&quot; /ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Disabled /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=true /TCPENABLED=1"
             Permanent="yes"/>
  <ExePackage Id="SQL2012Updatex64"
              InstallCondition="VersionNT64 AND (SQL2012x64InstanceInstalled AND SQLx64Version &lt; v11.0.0.0)"
              DisplayName="Upgrading SQL Server to SQL Server Express 2012..."
              InstallCommand='/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /HIDECONSOLE /ACTION=Upgrade /QUIET=True /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck'
              SourceFile="$(var.MyDir)\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"
              Permanent="yes"/>

  <ExePackage Id="SQL2012Expressx86"
              InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64 AND NOT SQL2012x86InstanceInstalled"
              SourceFile="$(var.MyDir)\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
              DisplayName="Installing Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 - Express Edition..."
              InstallCommand="/ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /Q /HIDECONSOLE /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE&quot; /AGTSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE&quot; /ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Disabled /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=true /TCPENABLED=1"
              Permanent="yes"/>
  <ExePackage Id="SQL2012Updatex86"
              InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64 AND (SQL2012x86InstanceInstalled AND SQLx86Version &lt; v11.0.0.0)"
              DisplayName="Upgrading SQL Server to SQL Server Express 2012..."
              InstallCommand='/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /HIDECONSOLE /ACTION=Upgrade /QUIET=True /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck'
              SourceFile="$(var.MyDir)\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
              Permanent="yes"/>

</PackageGroup>
```

Hope it helps you.

-- Naga Sreenivas Gupta V